# Arabic Characters In JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, utf-8

I have the following JSON with Arabic characters which I am sending to a REST controller. My problem is that the Arabic characters come-in as ?. Any ideas?

JSON is as follows. Request content type is "application/json;charset=UTF-8".

```
[
   { 
      "articleNumber":"1052",
      "genericArticle":"",
      "modelNumber":"FGTD18V5C/F/GW/MW",
      "articleDescription":"1052",
      "articleArabicDescription":"ثلاجة",
   }
]
```

Java Jackson Annotated class

```
public class Article {

    @JsonProperty
    private String articleNumber;
    @JsonProperty
    private String genericArticle;
    @JsonProperty
    private String modelNumber;
    @JsonProperty
    private String articleDescription;
    @JsonProperty
    private String articleArabicDescription;
}
```

Java REST Controller class

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/articles")
public class ArticlesController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseCounts createOrUpdate(@RequestBody List<Article> articles) {
        return;
    }
}
```

When I check what comes into this method after sending the above JSON, I get a single object in the list as expected but the **articleArabicDescription** data member shows question marks. Any ideas?

Many thanks

Patrick

Comment: " shows question marks" *what* shows question marks? If this is in a terminal, can it print unicode characters?

Comment: The IntelliJ Debugger shows ?????. I placed the breakpoint on the "return" statement.

Comment: What happens if you add `consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"` to your method (right after `produces=...`)?

Comment: @LinosaysReinstateMonica Just tried your suggestion and no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `produces` parameter is responsible for a `@ResponseBody` encoding whereas your problem is in the `@RequestBody` so try to add a `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` into the `@RequestMapping` definition

Comment: Solved it by adding the following to the JVM argunents: -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -Dsun.jnu.encoding="UTF-8"